# Pyinstaller ImportError on own module

Tags: python, module, pyinstaller

i have two modules next to each other within a package like this:

```
main/
|--> __init__.py
|--> somePackageName/
    |--> __init__.py
    |--> module1.py
    |--> module2.py
```

In module module1.py, I am importing module2.py with this statement:

`from .module1 import *`

When I run `python -m somePackageName.module1`, the script works just fine (Command executed from outside the package)

I now want to build an .exe with pyinstaller. After executing `pyinstaller module1.spec` I get the error:

**ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

[15800] Failed to execute script module1**

Sidenote: I get the same error, when I try to run `python module1.py` from inside the package.
Sidenote2: Do I need to work with hidden-imports and/or additional-hooks-dir ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relative imports work only inside packages. From what you are describing, I think that you are converting module1.py into a .exe so it is no longer inside a package.

You need to do the following:

- have a bootstrap module outside of your package, which uses your package facilities
- call pyinstaller on your bootstrap module

This would yield something like:

```
main/
|--> runme.py
|--> __init__.py
|--> somePackageName/
    |--> __init__.py
    |--> module1.py
    |--> module2.py
```

Your runme.py would be like:

```
import module1.main
module1.main()
```

Then your module1 import will work correctly.

The next step is to package runme.py into an executable with pyinstaller. I just tested it, it works fine.